# DropDownList causes error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I keep getting this error and have no idea why. I googled and scanned the asp.net site for two days now so I need some help. The error is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here's my code:

```
DropDownList DropDownList1 =(DropDownList)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList1");

string highToLow = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
string lowToHigh = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

if (highToLow == "1")
{
    var exmapleFilter = from users in testEntities.users 
                        orderby users.id descending
                        select users;

    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

I have the value of the drop down set to 1 for high and 2 for low, and on selected index changed I want to run the ADO.net Entity Framework code to return a sorted list of data.

I'm currently using a linq data source and a list view to show what's in my database.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the stack trace

```
   System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Source=App_Web_s0ked5y3

   StackTrace:
   at Default.DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   in Default:line 120

   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()

   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.
   RaisePostDataChangedEvent()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: This line gets highlighted as the error  DropDownList DropDownList1 =(DropDownList)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList1");

Comment: How do i get the stack trace? (what I get for skipping the debugging sections in books)

Comment: Please copy/paste the code in your post on Line 120 of Default.aspx.cs

Comment: are you sure that your code "(DropDownList)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList1");"...does return an instance of the dropdown...I would recommend you to put a break point on that line and use immediate window (use Ctrl+Alt+i) to run this code and see if it returns an instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have in your list view

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
   ....          
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" />
   ....
```

In association with

```
ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList1");
```

Comment: Hi VOX check in InsertItemTemplate no just in item template

Comment: But its blank I'm not using it to insert I'm only using the list view to display my data

Comment: Hang on i am really confused now lol I think I see my problem but when I changed ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList1"); to ListView1.ItemTemplate.FindControl("DropDownList1"); I got 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl

Comment: No try by changing    <ItemTemplate> ---> <InsertItemTemplate>,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13484/discussion-between-aghilas-yakoub-and-v0x)

Answer (score 0):

Based on their is no stack trace my doubt is the line:

```
DropDownList DropDownList1 =
    (DropDownList)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList1");
```

Is causing oObject reference not set to an instance of an object

One strong reason: The control called InsertItem is not a child control of ListView1

Answer (score 0):

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception generally occurs when your are trying to use the reference variable whose value is null. It means that there is not corresponding object on heap.

So please make sure to double check your template and load all values in pageload event.

Hope it helps.